# Why are resolution, pixel aspect ratio, and sensor size not linked in Blender?

Tags: camera

## Background

So I wrote this lil' python script to obtain the camera matrix (intrinsics times extrinsics) from my scene and its active camera. It's been working great, under the following settings.

> Render resolution: `x = 1000`; `y = 1000`
>
> Sensor size: `width = 50`; `height = 50`
>
> Pixel aspect ratio (PAR): `x / y = 1`

Today, I used my script under a new setting,

> Render resolution: `x = 1920`; `y = 1080`
>
> Sensor size: `width = 50`; `height = 18`
>
> PAR: `x / y = 1`

and my camera matrix projects a point (which appears inside the camera as per the viewport, i.e., the "<kbd>numpad0</kbd> view") to a negative `y` pixel value -- outside the frame!

I thought about it, and it makes sense. The (imaginary) physical sensor is shorter in height (18) than in width (50), and I am (unreasonably) demanding unproportional resolutions and a PAR of 1. Inevitably, some of the 1080 pixels in the `y` direction fall outside of the physical sensor!

## Questions

1. Is my analysis above correct?
2. If so, why does Blender still show me the complete rendering (instead of the partial photo truncated in the `y` direction), even if I'm being unreasonable?
3. An even higher-level question: why aren't these three quantities---resolution, pixel aspect ratio, and sensor size---coupled in Blender? If a ridiculous user like myself is demanding

> Render resolution: `x = 1920`; `y = 1080`
>
> PAR: `x / y = 1`

shouldn't the sensor size be constrained to a fixed, computable value already?